# Controller with generic object in dotnet

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to make a CQRS pattern in my ASP.NET API. I've made some dispatchers to handle all my command objects. Now I want to have a generic controller with one method named command that can accept ANY object in body. So I can cast it and use it with my dispatcher. I'm not sure how to do that.

Maybe something like this?

```
public class CommandController<TCommand> : Controller where TCommand : class
{
   [HttpPost]
   public async Task<IActionResult> Command([FromBody]TCommand command)
   {
   }
}
```

The route should be /api/command/genericCommand

Comment: Do different `TCommand`s have anything in common other than inheriting `class`?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, we couldn't achieve accept ANY object in body. Asp.net core provide a model binding by default to bind the request body to a model.

But if we want to deserialize the request body to the model, we need to know the model format and then we could use reflect to deserialize the request body to the model.

We need also know the body format and the body model name, like json, xml or else, and then we could build the custom model binding to bind to different model.

Comment: You can implement custom model binding.

Comment: I know we could implement custom model binding, but we need to know what is Tcommand and then we could use custom model binding.

Answer (score -1):

```cs
public class CommandController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Command([FromBody]CommonBase command)
    {
        switch (command)
        {
            case Derived1 d1:
                // ...
                break;
            case Derived1 d2:
                // ...
                break;
            // ...
            default:
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure why the downvote, but based on the given information in the question this is one possible approach to the problem.